# How to Click movement in unity and stop if there is Collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have an issue about movement click on unity it's about when I click of course the player will be moving to the position I clicked but, I don't want if I clicked on the wall and another button the player will be on the last mouse I clicked, I already add some collider but the player just bypass the collider so collider doesn't have any effect

[the explanation](https://media.giphy.com/media/mFNailNh5CXLTlxHN3/giphy.gif)

and this the script

```
[Header("Tweak")]
[SerializeField] Transform target;
Vector2 targetPos;
public float speed = 5f;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    targetPos = transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Move();
}

public void Move()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        targetPos = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if ((targetPos.x >= transform.position.x))
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(.5f, .5f);  
        }
        else
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(-.5f, .5f);
        }
        target.position = targetPos;
    }
    if ((Vector2)transform.position != targetPos)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark this question as solved, if your requirement is fulfilled.

Comment: @kodesensei well I know that but this not  solve my problem :D

Comment: so what are you looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Raycast

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
     {
         Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
         RaycastHit hitInfo;
         if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
         {
             if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
             {
                 Debug.Log("tag");
                 //You can do what ever you want here.
             }
         }
     }
```